# `$ socketstream start` not working

Tags: socketstream

I installed SocketStream and created a demo app with the `socketstream new [appname]` command.  It worked fine, but I was only able to start it with `node app` command.  Some reference suggests using `socketstream start` from the command prompt. When I tried this it responded with a usage suggestion: "try `socketstream new [project name]`".

I also installed SocketChat, and their Github documentation suggests starting with `socketstream start`.  It just prompts usage suggestion as above to create a new project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like they've deprecated the standalone chat app, as last update 2 years ago.  It's integrated into the main template now.

And `socketstream start` to start an application seems (best guess) to be deprecated or removed for v 0.3+